# Configure IntelliJ Java exception breakpoint

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, conditional-statements, breakpoints

Is there a way to configure an IntelliJ Java exception breakpoint so that it only triggers when the bottom class in the stack trace is a specific class?  For example, with the stack trace below, I'd like to break only when the bottom line contains the class `ComputeLCAInBinaryTreeSpec`.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4

    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.common.BinaryTreeNode.buildBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode.groovy:62)
    at com.common.BinaryTreeNode.buildBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode.groovy:76)
    at com.common.BinaryTreeNode.buildBinaryTrees_closure1(BinaryTreeNode.groovy:53)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at com.common.BinaryTreeNode.buildBinaryTrees(BinaryTreeNode.groovy:51)
    at com.elementsofprogramminginterviews.binarytrees.ComputeLCAInBinaryTreeSpec.computes LCA of two nodes of a binary tree_closure1(ComputeLCAInBinaryTreeSpec.groovy:65)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at com.elementsofprogramminginterviews.binarytrees.ComputeLCAInBinaryTreeSpec.computes LCA of two nodes of a binary tree(ComputeLCAInBinaryTreeSpec.groovy:47)
```

Comment: You may be able to leverage exception breakpoints. I've never personally used them but you can set conditions as well as filters. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-exception-breakpoints.html for details

Answer (score 5):

You should be able use breaking on any exception with [conditions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/breakpoints-2.html#d690810e140) to achieve this. Similar to my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028088/can-intellij-idea-be-configured-to-break-on-exceptions-in-junit-tests-that-lets#44042135) (maybe it's of interest to someone), just get the stacktrace, and check if it contains your class (or if it's the first one in the hierarchy):

[image: condition]